# Regular Expression to match a string that occurs within the same group as another string

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Apologies if this has been asked before - I'm having trouble articulating what I want.

Imagine I'm searching through hundreds of html files:

I want to match all the occurrences of CSS classes that are bound to another css class. For example, given the following:

```
<div class="btn-sm btn-red orange float-left"></div>
<div class="btn-red btn-sm float-left orange"></div>
<div class="btn-sm btn-red float-left"></div>
<div class="btn-sm btn-red orange float-left"></div>
<div class="orange btn-red  btn-sm  float-left"></div>
<div class="orange btn-sm btn-red float-left"></div>
```

I want to match `btn-sm` every time `orange` is also within the string.  So the result would look like this:

```
<div class="btn-sm btn-red orange float-left"></div> --- MATCH
<div class="btn-red btn-sm float-left orange"></div> --- MATCH
<div class="btn-sm btn-red float-left"></div>  --- NO MATCH!
<div class="btn-sm btn-red orange float-left"></div>  -- MATCH
<div class="orange btn-red  btn-sm  float-left"></div> -- MATCH
<div class="btn-sm btn-red float-left"></div> -- NO MATCH!
```

The point is that if `orange` is anywhere in that string, I'd want to match `btn-sm`, but if `orange` wasn't there I wouldn't want to match `btn-sm`. Both `btn-sm` and `orange` could be anywhere in the  string.

Comment: I don't know if your exact question has been asked before, but in general using regex to parse HTML/XML content is a bad idea.  What programming language were you planning to use here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I just want to remove a class - I'm using Sublime Here.  Cleaning up 100's of files at once rather than piece by piece.